# ravendb python api, query always return 128

Tags: python, ravendb

I'm querying my ravendb instance. My target collection contain more than 30k documents. I'm using pyravendb with python 3.

I'm querying my index using the following code :

```
result_ = self.store.database_commands.query(index_name="Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                                                    index_query=IndexQuery("Tag:MyCollection",total_size=128,skipped_results=start))
if len(result_['Results']) < 128:
     return
```

start being the offset variable that increments by 128 each time I query.
When I run this code the result's length is always 128 which leads to an infinite loop.

Any ideas why it acts like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the parameter I was using. The proper parameter that should be used is **start = offset_that_you_want_to_skip** and not **skipped_results=offset**.

the correct code is the following :

```
result_ = self.store.database_commands.query(index_name="Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                                                    index_query=IndexQuery("Tag:MyCollection",total_size=128,skipped_results=0, default_operator=None,start=offset)) 
#blablabla
offset+=128
if len(result_['Results']) < 128:
         return
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look here in my commit
[Get all of a collection's documents id's RavenDB for a "per-document" modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907922/get-all-of-a-collections-documents-ids-ravendb-for-a-per-document-modificati/42922507#comment72992181_42922507)

In pyravendb v3.5.3.5 I updated the IndexQuery and now you able to skip or to take less or more documents then 128.

The other thing don't use total_size or skipped_results (They are going to be removed)

Comment: I removed them and opened a pull request. Hope you will accept my simple contribution to the awesome RavenDB :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly going to answer your question but did you consider using RavenDB's streaming functionality? https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-stream-query-results

In many cases when dealing with a large number of documents this might be faster and simpler compared to iterating with Query().

However please be aware that streamed objects will not be tracked. Meaning changes to these objects and a consequent SaveChanges()-call wont have any effect to the documents stored within RavenDB.

Comment: Seems to be like there is a bug in the function, it should not return 128 if there is only <128 docs left in the collection.

Comment: Which client library are you using?

Comment: Pyravendb (api for python)

Comment: If you look at the query method https://github.com/ravendb/RavenDB-Python-Client/blob/master/pyravendb/d_commands/database_commands.py#L241
and at the IndexQuery class https://github.com/ravendb/RavenDB-Python-Client/blob/8342a6f53558a6668774df71868b2fb618f2c484/pyravendb/data/indexes.py#L111 the parameters total_size and skipped_results seem not to be used at all.
Futhermore those two parameters have a comment that says "For internal use only" (whatever that means...)

Comment: Well, i will have to query the db (even if i think that querying the index would be a better way to do this).. I just want to get all id's in the db and RavenDB already indexes id's in Raven/DocumentsByEntityName..